# Android Local Notification

Tags: android, notifications

I need to show a local notification in android in title bar when certain event occurs. I want the notification also play certain sound as well.

On tap  of notification I want app should not be launched and notification should be cleared.

I am using this code but on tap of notification it opens my app again.

```
        CharSequence title = "App title";
        CharSequence message = "This to alert you that estimated time is getting complete.";

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Title", System.currentTimeMillis());

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, JobView.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(JobView.this, title, message, null);
        notificationManager.notify(1010, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CharSequence title = "App title";
CharSequence message = "This to alert you that estimated time is getting complete.";

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Title", System.currentTimeMillis());
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

builder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.YOUR_SOUND_FILE);
notificationManager.notify(1234, builder.build());
```

Just replace the File Reference from your `Raw` folder in the code and the code should work fine.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CharSequence title = "App title";
CharSequence message = "This to alert you that estimated time is getting complete.";

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                  .setAutoCancel(true)
                  .setContentTitle(title);

mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                  + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound));
mBuilder.setContentText(message);
mBuilder.setTicker(message);
mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

NotificationManager notificationManager =   
       (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(1010, mBuilder.build());
```

Change `R.raw.sound` with path to your sound file